# Makefile: Compile C++ Files recursively

Tags: c++, makefile

I am new to makefiles and tried reading resources on the internet to solve my problem, yet I am unable to find a solution.

Basically I am working on a project which contains C++ and Cuda files. Since I like to keep my things structured, I usually use a nested folder structure like this:

```
 |- bin
 |- build
 |  |- cc
 |  |- cu
 |- src
 |- makefile
 |- main.cpp
```

My current Makefile looks like this:

```
CC       = g++
NVCC     = nvcc
CC_SRC   = $(wildcard *.cpp */*.cpp */*/*.cpp */*/*/*.cpp)
CU_SRC   = $(wildcard *.cu */*.cu */*/*.cu */*/*/*.cu)

CC_LIBS  = -pthread -Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -Wl,--no-whole-archive

ROOT     = ./
FOLDER   = $(ROOT)bin/
OBJECTS  = $(ROOT)build/
CC_OBJ   = $(OBJECTS)cc/
CU_OBJ   = $(OBJECTS)cu/
NAME     = Test
EXE      = $(ROOT)$(FOLDER)$(NAME)

NVCC_FLAGS =
CC_FLAGS =

## Compile ##
run:build

build: $(EXE)

$(CC_SRC):
    @echo compiling
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $a

$(EXE) : $(CC_SRC)
    @echo test 123
```

Initially I wanted to compile all `C++` files to the `build/cc` files. Similarly my `.cu` files should be compiled into the `build/cu` folder.

Initially I made a wildcard which catches all the `c++` files:

```
CC_SRC   = $(wildcard *.cpp */*.cpp */*/*.cpp */*/*/*.cpp)
CU_SRC   = $(wildcard *.cu */*.cu */*/*.cu */*/*/*.cu)
```

But for some reason the according rule is not being executed. I am happy if someone could help me here.

Greetings
Finn

Comment: What rule are you referring to? There are no rules in the shown Makefile which attempts to compile anything, and the rule that builds the executable declares that the executable depends on all the source files, directly, and the way to build the executable is to execute the `echo` command. As Mr. Spock would say: this is not logical.

Comment: Why do you want to rebuild `$(CC_SRC)`? Those are the primary sources. Your build target should be something like `$(CC_OBJ)` where ,o is substituted for .cpp and `$(OBJECTS)cc/` is substituted for `$(basename $src .cpp)`. Then your `$(EXE)` needs to depend on the OBJ files instead of the source files.

Comment: You are right in that. Yet I simply wanted to have a rule which is being executed for every single source file. Or am I wrong in that? So there are a few rules missing. My main rule should simply create the object files for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule doesn't make sense:

```
$(CC_SRC):
        @echo compiling
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $a
```

(I assume you mean `$@` here not `$a`).  This rule says that the way to create each of the source files is by compiling them.  But, make doesn't need to build the source files: they already exist.  So it never invokes your rule.

You need your target to be the file you want to *create*, not the file that already exists.  The file you want to create is the object file, not the source file.  Then the prerequisite is the file that already exists.  So for a compilation you want a pattern rule, like this:

```
$(CC_OBJ)%.o : %.cpp
        @echo compiling
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Then you want your target to depend on the object files, not the source files, like this:

```
$(EXE) : $(CC_SRC:%.cpp=$(CC_OBJ)%.o)
        @echo test 123
```

Comment: Oh yeah wow that makes more sense. The syntax is really not trivial but it makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend migrating your project to CMake (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/), in particular if your project is not too big yet.

Makefiles can be really a pain; CMake can ease matters considerably.